# Searching a reactive array in Vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs3

In Vue.js 3 (beta), I have defined an array using `reactive`, as I want to bind its contents to some UI controls in a loop. So far, this works and everything is fine.

Now, I need to update a value within this array, which means I need to run a `find` or a `findIndex` on this array. Since the array is being proxied by Vue.js, this doesn't work as expected: The proxy is just not a simple plain old array.

What I did is get a copy using `toRaw`, run `findIndex` on that one, and then update the original array using the index. This works, but of course it doesn't seem to be very elegant.

Is there a better way to approach this?

PS: It's fine if it's a solution that only works in Vue 3, I don't care about the 2.x series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the array's methods are still accessible through the `Proxy`, so you can still use `find` or `findIndex` on it:

```js
import { reactive } from 'vue'

const items = reactive([1,2,3])

console.log(items.find(x => x % 2 === 0))
console.log(items.findIndex(x => x % 2 === 0))
```

```js
const MyApp = {
  setup() {
    const items = Vue.reactive([1,2,3])
    
    return {
      items,
      addItem() {
        items.push(items.length + 1)
      },
      logFirstEvenValue() {
        console.log(items.find(x => x % 2 === 0))
      },
      logFirstEvenIndex() {
        console.log(items.findIndex(x => x % 2 === 0))
      },
      incrementItems() {
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          items[i]++
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(MyApp).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.5"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="logFirstEvenValue">Log first even item</button>
  <button @click="logFirstEvenIndex">Log index of first even item</button>
  <button @click="incrementItems">Increment items</button>
  <button @click="addItem">Add item</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You're right – it seems as if I had done something completely wrong before, but don't ask me what it was… I just removed the `toRaw` call, and it works perfectly 